# Danfo js setting columns in specific order I want

Tags: javascript

Danfo js for setting column header in order I specify.

I want to set columns in order like pandas df where the grammar is like:
df= df[['1','2']]

The above code sets df columns in the same way the list is in the outer square brackets like "1", "2".

Is there any equivalent option to danfo?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.